# Is copying entities from one app to another to backup your data recommended?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I'm referring tothe datastore admin tool explained here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html

One way of backing up locally is by using bulkloader.py, but I'm liking this solution better as your data stays in Google's cloud and can be easily transferred from one app to the other using a button in the admin console on an entity by entity basis. thinking of having two apps, one that i can manually back up to every week, and another that actually serves users. The backup app might incur some storage costs but overall costs would be minimal as no front/backend instances would be used except as needed for the backups...

Comment: What would be the benefit of bothering to do this at all?  Your data (in both apps) will be inaccessible if Google has an outage.  If Google doesn't have an outage, then they have their own backup systems.

Comment: One wrong line of code and your data can get ruined, if such a thing happens, you can restore the affected model with one click based on the last backup of that model. That's just one scenario. But you're right that if Google is down, the data will be locked in both. If that happens for an extendederiod and you want to change platforms, then ou've got a much bigger problem of porting your app to something like AWS or Heroku. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up one GAE app's data to another app is certainly not recommended by me. To me, there are a handful of reasons to backup:

1. To safeguard against a catastrophic outage on Google's part.
2. To safeguard against a programming error on your part that results in significant data loss.
3. To safeguard against your Google account being revoked.

Backing up to another GAE app does relatively little on each of these.

1. If you use the [High Replication datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/hr/overview.html), you're already distributing your data all across Google's cloud, so doing that again just seems redundant -- but not in the high availability sense of the word. The only way Google is going to lose your data is through some catastrophic disaster, in which case both of your apps may be in peril.
2. If you backup your data locally, you can store historic snapshots. Whereas if you're simply backing up to another app, you aren't storing historic data, so you have little protection against programmer error unless you catch it in between the time the error happens and when you're going to do your next backup.
3. In the event that Google, for whatever reason, kills your account, you lose both apps and all your data.

Ultimately, by backing up to another GAE, you still have all your eggs in one basket. You've just partitioned your basket. If your data is important enough to be backed up outside of your app, it's important enough to backup locally or to another provider entirely. That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: Love your explanation. Thanks Ken. So for now you're using bulkloader as a way to store historic snapshots on disk?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, I use app_cfg to download all my data periodically, especially just before an update. Even better would be scheduling it on a cronjob.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that there is an experimental tool going out in 1.6.2 that will allow you to do backups. I don't have any details now - just stay tuned and be on the lookout for the new SDK when it drops.

Answer (score 1):

We backup our data periodically to another application to use as our development environment, but as others pointed out that's not really protecting your data against a major appengine catastrophe (as unlikely as this is...).

The best solution I've found for archiving data for disaster recovery is to pull it down using the python scripts google provides either onto EC2 or local disk.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Can you elaborate a little bit more on what kind of setup you have with EC2?

Comment: We use a combination of shell scripts to pull down our blobstore to flat files and the datastore to csv files and some intermediate relationship mapping files and then just save that on an EBS drive. We snapshot the EBS periodically in order to have backups.